# WCF-BasicHttp NTLM ESB guidance

Tags: wcf, biztalk, basichttpbinding, esb-toolkit-2.0

I am trying to access an asmx service located on IIS, the asmx is using integradted security
I am trying to call it with wcf-basichttp adapter configured inside ESB guidance 1.0

The error i am getting is :

> The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme 'Anonymous'. The authentication header received from the server was 'NTLM'

I tryed to set in the endpoint config:

```
UserName=DOMAIN\Username&Password=Password&TransportClientCredentialType=NTLM
```

Any idea would be appriciated

Comment: SHOW US THE WCF CLIENT CONFIG !!

Comment: Its the ESB guidance, the ports are created dynamickly with endpoint config parameters directly to the wcf port

Comment: I have re-tagged this as esb-toolkit-2.0 to make it more discoverable even though the question mentions ESB Guidance 1.0. But in fact, the answer would be appropriate for both versions.

Answer (score 0):

I would take a look at this similar [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1044034/wcftestclient-the-http-request-is-unauthorized-with-client-authentication-scheme).