# Changing SSRS service account causes "HTTP request is unauthorized" error in report deployment app

Tags: security, soap, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have a C# application that I wrote to deploy reports to a SSRS instance. It has been working well. To improve security, I decided to change SSRS from using the NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE account to using a dedicated domain account. I used the Reporting Services Configuration Manager to make the change. Now my app throws a MessageSecurityException:

The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme 'Negotiate'. The authentication header received from the server was 'Negotiate oYGEMIGBoAMKAQGiegR4YHYGCSqGSIb3EgECAgMAfmcwZaADAgEFoQMCAR6kERgPMjAxMjA3MjQxNzIyNTBapQUCAwUAuaYDAgEpqQ4bDFZFUlRFWC5MT0NBTKoqMCigAwIBA6EhMB8bBGhvc3QbF3Z0eC1kZXYtMDEudmVydGV4LmxvY2Fs'.

I call the following method:

```
public static ReportService.ReportingService2010SoapClient Connect(StreamWriter logFile, string reportingServicesUri)
{
    //Connect with the user's Windows credentials
    try
    {
        BasicHttpBinding basicHttpBinding = new BasicHttpBinding();
        basicHttpBinding.Security.Mode = BasicHttpSecurityMode.TransportCredentialOnly;
        basicHttpBinding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Windows;
        basicHttpBinding.SendTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 10, 0);
        EndpointAddress endpoint = new EndpointAddress(reportingServicesUri);
        var rs = new ReportService.ReportingService2010SoapClient(basicHttpBinding, endpoint);
        rs.ClientCredentials.Windows.AllowedImpersonationLevel = System.Security.Principal.TokenImpersonationLevel.Impersonation;
        rs.ChannelFactory.Credentials.Windows.ClientCredential = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
        return rs;
    }
    catch (UriFormatException)
    {
        Common.WriteToLog(logFile, "Connect: " + reportingServicesUri + " does not point to a valid SSRS instance.", false);
    }

    return null;
}
```

I then call this method (which is where the exception is caught):

```
private static CatalogItem FindFirstItem(ReportingService2010SoapClient rs, StreamWriter logFile, String itemPath, String itemName)
{
    CatalogItem[] items;
    var itemsNames = new string[] { itemName };
    string indentText = "";
    Console.WriteLine(indentText + "Searching for " + itemPath + '/' + itemName + "...");

    try
    {
        TrustedUserHeader userHeader = new TrustedUserHeader();
        var properties = new Property[1];
        properties[0] = new Property();
        properties[0].Name = "Recursive";
        properties[0].Value = "false";
        var conditions = new SearchCondition[1];
        conditions[0] = new SearchCondition();
        conditions[0].Condition = ConditionEnum.Equals;
        conditions[0].ConditionSpecified = true;
        conditions[0].Name = "Name";
        conditions[0].Values = itemsNames;
        rs.FindItems(userHeader, "/" + itemPath, BooleanOperatorEnum.And, properties, conditions, out items);

        if (items.Length == 0)
            return null;

        return items[0];
    }
    catch (FaultException e)
    {
        if (!e.Message.Contains("cannot be found"))
            Common.WriteToLog(logFile, "FindFirstItem: " + e.Message, false);
    }
    catch (MessageSecurityException e)
    {
        throw;
    }

    return null;
}
```

I can still access the Data Sources for this SSRS instance using the Report Manager URL in a browser. My app still works on SSRS instances that use NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE as the service account. How can I get this app working again with this SSRS instance?

Answer (score 0):

[WCFTestClient The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme 'Anonymous'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1044034/wcftestclient-the-http-request-is-unauthorized-with-client-authentication-scheme)

```
Customer_PortClient proxy = new Customer_PortClient();
proxy.ClientCredentials.Windows.AllowedImpersonationLevel =    
         System.Security.Principal.TokenImpersonationLevel.Impersonation;
```