# The http request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme 'Anonymous' when using credential identity

Tags: c#, wcf, soap

I'm trying to connect to a SOAP service using the WCF Client generator tool in Visual Studio 2017. However, when I make a request, I get this error:

> "The http request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme 'Anonymous'".

I'm trying to use certificate authentication. This is my App.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1" />
    </startup>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <diagnostics performanceCounters="Default" />
        <behaviors>
            <endpointBehaviors>
                <behavior name="NewBehavior0">
                    <clientCredentials useIdentityConfiguration="true">
                        <clientCertificate findValue="portalservicos.jucemg.mg.gov.br"
                            storeLocation="LocalMachine" storeName="TrustedPeople" x509FindType="FindByIssuerName" />
                        <serviceCertificate>
                            <authentication certificateValidationMode="PeerOrChainTrust"
                                trustedStoreLocation="LocalMachine" />
                        </serviceCertificate>
                    </clientCredentials>
                </behavior>
            </endpointBehaviors>
        </behaviors>
        <bindings>
            <basicHttpBinding>
                <binding name="NewBinding2">
                    <security mode="Transport">
                        <transport clientCredentialType="Certificate" />
                    </security>
                </binding>
            </basicHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="https://newsrm.jucemg.mg.gov.br:443/empreendimento/service/ViabilidadePrefeituraWS"
                behaviorConfiguration="NewBehavior0" binding="basicHttpBinding"
                bindingConfiguration="NewBinding2" contract="ViabilidadePrefeituraWS.ViabilidadePrefeituraWS"
                name="ViabilidadePrefeituraWSPort">
            </endpoint>
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

This is my code:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var ws = new ViabilidadePrefeituraWSClient();
        ws.callService("");
    }
}
```

When I set a breakpoint there, I see that the certificate is indeed being loaded (`ws.ClientCredentials.ClientCertificate` shows the correct certificate). Somehow though, it seems that the certificate is not being sent, or the configuration is somehow not being used, since the error mentions Authentication Scheme "Anonymous".

I saw this question ([WCFTestClient The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme 'Anonymous'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1044034/wcftestclient-the-http-request-is-unauthorized-with-client-authentication-scheme)) and other similar questions, however none of them were about using certificates to authenticate.

Comment: Hi did you resolve this? Facing something similar. Thanks

Comment: @tjeuten I think so, but I don't really remember none of it anymore :( Sorry. If I do, I ping you here