# The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme 'Anonymous'. The authentication header received from the server was 'Negotiate'

Tags: soap, wsdl, wcf-binding

I am trying to connect SOAP/WSDL web service using client certificate authentication, client and server both end certificate is installed but when we are trying to communicate using `WSHttpBinding`, `SecurityMode = Transport` and `ClientCredentialType = Certificate`, I'm getting below error

> The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme 'Anonymous'. The authentication header received from the server was 'Negotiate'

WSHttpBinding with a certificate as a credential type

[image: WSHttpBinding]

how to access service

[image: access services]

I had tried many solutions still not getting success

Comment: Please don't post pictures of code

Comment: You can refer to the answer to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1044034/wcftestclient-the-http-request-is-unauthorized-with-client-authentication-scheme