# Service Soap Client WebService not authorized .NET/C#

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, .net-4.6.1

I'm trying to call a method for a web service we use. I keep getting this error

**The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme 'Anonymous'. The authentication header received from the server was 'Negotiate, NTLM'.**

The reference file shows that the class is a sub class of ClientBase.

I'm able to see the Web.Config file but not manipulate it. This is what it shows for binding.

```
    <bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="basicHttpBindingWinAuthConf" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="2000000000" maxArrayLength="2000000000" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
      <security mode="Transport">
        <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
  <webHttpBinding>
    <binding name="webHttpBindingConf">
      <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
        <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </webHttpBinding>
  <customBinding>
    <binding name="binaryHttpBindingSecuredFalse" maxSessionSize="2000000000">
      <binaryMessageEncoding>
        <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="2000000000" maxArrayLength="2000000000" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
      </binaryMessageEncoding>
      <httpTransport maxReceivedMessageSize="2000000000" transferMode="StreamedResponse" authenticationScheme="Negotiate" />
    </binding>
    <binding name="binaryHttpBindingSecuredTrue" maxSessionSize="2000000000">
      <binaryMessageEncoding>
        <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="2000000000" maxArrayLength="2000000000" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
      </binaryMessageEncoding>
      <httpsTransport maxReceivedMessageSize="2000000000" transferMode="StreamedResponse" authenticationScheme="Negotiate" />
    </binding>
    <binding name="binaryHttpBindingSecured" maxSessionSize="2000000000">
      <binaryMessageEncoding>
        <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="2000000000" maxArrayLength="2000000000" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
      </binaryMessageEncoding>
      <httpsTransport maxReceivedMessageSize="2000000000" transferMode="StreamedResponse" authenticationScheme="Negotiate" />
    </binding>
    <binding name="binaryHttpBinding" maxSessionSize="2000000000">
      <binaryMessageEncoding>
        <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="2000000000" maxArrayLength="2000000000" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
      </binaryMessageEncoding>
      <httpTransport maxReceivedMessageSize="2000000000" transferMode="StreamedResponse" authenticationScheme="Negotiate" />
    </binding>
  </customBinding>
</bindings>
```

I've tried the code below to authorize my call

```
       BasicHttpBinding bind = new BasicHttpBinding();
   bind.Security.Mode = BasicHttpSecurityMode.TransportCredentialOnly;
   bind.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Windows;
   EndpointAddress endpoint = new EndpointAddress("http://uri_to_service/transactionservices.asmx");
```

Before the update I would use this line of code and it worked as it should

```
 TS.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
```

What am I doing wrong?

UPDATE

I've also tried this and had no luck...

```
            TS.ChannelFactory.Credentials.Windows.ClientCredential = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials; 
        TS.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
```

Some have suggested this but did not work....

```
TS.ClientCredentials.Windows.AllowedImpersonationLevel = System.Security.Principal.TokenImpersonationLevel.Impersonation;
```

looking into the web config file I saw this so I don't it would work anyways..

```
<authentication mode="Windows" />
<identity impersonate="false" />
```

Any ideas?

Comment: `Before the update` what update? Did you switch from .NET Framework to .NET Core? .NET 5 and .NET 6 are actually .NET *Core* versions.

Comment: The company that created the service updated it where the code that worked before no longer has Credentials as a property to set. Looks like they rewrote the class and how it connects to them. The pacakges.config file targetFramework is net462

Comment: Maybe you can check [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1044034/wcftestclient-the-http-request-is-unauthorized-with-client-authentication-scheme) and [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/developer/webapps/iis/www-authentication-authorization/access-denied-call-web-service) to find a solution.

Comment: I've read through this thread before and no luck. The doc shows examples of how I was able to set Credentials before but now Credentials property is longer available to set.

Comment: you can look at [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/msp-n-p/ff648505(v=pandp.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN).

Comment: My app is written in net core 3.1 and looks like connecting to web reference (SOAP) written in target framework 4.6.1.....net core does not have the same references so I get errors trying to reference it. I've used the tool svcutil.exe and I get this error

Warning: Cannot import wsdl:portType
Detail: An exception was thrown while running a WSDL import extension: System.ServiceModel.Description.XmlSerializerMessageContractImporter
Error: Referenced type 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/:Array' is only valid for encoded SOAP.

Comment: Also why does 4.6.1 create a reference with no problem and core gets a bunch of errors and does not give the same references?

Comment: Because .net core does not support WCF full functionality https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48522849/what-replaces-wcf-in-net-core